# ¿cómo mantener el color del background al cambiar el tema del navegador?

Tags: html, css

Actualmente tengo un color específico en el body de una plantilla HTML y necesito que ese color se mantenga independientemente del tema del navegador, puesto que por ejemplo, en modo dark, se oscurece mi plantilla y necesito que el background quede fijo.

Gracias por cualquier guia o colaboración

Comment: Solo agregale un color de fondo al Body.. Si no lo tiene en modo claro pone el blanco y modo oscuro el gris oscuro..

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Por defecto, el **color del body está predefinido por el navegador**, por eso asegúrate de que este estilo esté en tu archivo CSS para **decirle al navegador que el color del body es ese** (en el código de ejemplo es #FFFFFF):

```
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Las reglas CSS se aplican en orden, por lo que las reglas que aparecen más abajo en tu archivo CSS reemplazarán las reglas anteriores. **Mira si más abajo tienes media queries para otros tamaños de pantalla que anulen o cambien** esta propiedad.

Después de darle un color de fondo en el archivo CSS, **debería mantenerse independientemente del tema del navegador** cuando los usuarios cambien el tema de claro a oscuro, y tu fondo personalizado permanecerá constante.